# Visual Studio Code Setting Default Configurations

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, configuration-files

I'm just starting to code C++ with the VS Code.
Is it possible to set default configurations (json files) for each project?
Right now I have to manually create these files and configure them for each program.

Thanks, Roie

Comment: Do you mean that whenever you create a new workspace the same tasks.json (as an example) will be generated?

Comment: Exactly. Without needing to configure for each project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be not possible currently. You can monitor this issue from the vscode Github: [Shared configuration (tasks/settings) #1435](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1435)

> Global tasks in a task.json file are still on the agenda (to get
>   parity with launch.json). However it is a matter of priorities when
>   they will come. (Oct 26, 2018)

So you would have to build something yourself like a python or bash script that automatically generates the json files for you.